# Create time corrected .srt subtitle file for .mkv which uses file/segment linking

Tags: subtitles, mkv, command-line

I have two mkv files. One of them is the episode of a series and the other one the opening which is linked in the first one. Let's call them `episode.mkv` resp. `opening.mkv`.

I also have a `subtitle.srt` which is used by a player (e.g. `mpv`) which contains the subtitle for `episode.mkv` and `opening.mkv`. Aslong as both files are present, there is no problem. But once `opening.mkv` is missing, `episode.mkv` and `subtitle.srt` are not synchoronized anymore of course.

Can you point me to cli tools that are aware of linked segments, which can automatically create a time corrected subtitle file from `episode.mkv, opening.mkv, subtitle.srt` that works with `episode.mkv` alone?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Will removing amount of time of opening.mkv and adjusting from new offset do the work? Then you may use ffmpeg.